# How to detect Mindstorm EV3 using flutter_blue

Tags: flutter, bluetooth, lego-mindstorms, lego-mindstorms-ev3

I am trying to setup a bluetooth server on a Mindstorm EV3 using ev3dev with python.

The server appears to work fine as it is a very basic implementation of the bluetooth server socket.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import bluetooth
from ev3dev2.sound import Sound

sound = Sound()

server_sock = bluetooth.BluetoothSocket(bluetooth.RFCOMM)

port = 1
server_sock.bind(("", port))
server_sock.listen(1)

sound.speak("Accepting connections on port " + str(port))

client_sock, address = server_sock.accept()
sound.speak("Accepted connection from " + str(address))

data = client_sock.recv(1024)
sound.speak("received " + str(data))

client_sock.close()
server_sock.close()
```

The problem I am having right now is the fact that I cannot seem to detect the bluetooth signal from the EV3 in my flutter app. I can find other devices just fine and I can find the EV3 in the bluetooth settings on the phone, it's just the app that doesn't detect it.

This is the code I use to detect bluetooth devices

```
_btSubscription = _flutterBlue.scan().listen((scanResult) {
    if (scanResult.device.name.isEmpty || _detectedDevices.contains(scanResult.device))
        return;

        print('Found Bluetooth device: (${scanResult.device.name})');

        _detectedDevices.add(scanResult.device);
```

The EV3 does have a name set so it is not being ignored because of the name check.

Any advice is appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I would suggest adding a `print()` before your `return;` to check if your result is actually empty or already has the device listed.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, I believe I already tried this, but I will make another attempt and report back if I get new findings :)

Comment: I tried adding a couple of prints just dumping information about any device that was found. I also tried filtering on the EV3's bluetooth address. But it yielded no results. In addition, I tested it with another computer that has bluetooth, and Flutter Blue is unable to detect that as well. So it seems it is specifically other computers it is unable to detect.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question, but posting this for future readers.

Note that there are many versions/variants of Bluetooth, and not all are compatible.   The flutter_blue package is for BLE (Low Energy) which a recent technology, introduced in Bluetooth 4.0, and common in phones since 2015
see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bluetooth#Specifications_and_features

The Lego EV3 uses Bluetooth V2.1 EDR, (Classic Bluetooth) as do older laptops, so this will be the reason that `flutterBlue.scan()` does not "see" these devices.
see also https://superuser.com/questions/502825/how-can-i-find-out-what-version-of-bluetooth-my-laptop-supports.

If you want to work in Flutter, with Bluetooth Classic,  look at other packages like https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_bluetooth_serial.  (I am not saying this will work with EV3, but at least is the right Bluetooth!)

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
We did try with bluetooth serial as well, also without luck as we did believe this to be the case.
In the end we ended up setting up an API on the EV3 and running the system over WiFi instead of Bluetooth as we decided that the technologies weren't mature enough. But it seems maturity isn't the right word to use for it, but rather incompatible :)